# How can I display 9 rows of results in a 3x3 grid?

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2012

I have a report that gathers data to be printed on labels, we want to print up to 9 labels per page, on a 3x3 grid.

Am I able to use something like groupings to get this layout generated automatically, or will I need to hard-code each of the 9 labels individually? I would like to be able to do it automatically so that I can re-purpose it for other label sizes.

I haven't tried anything yet, as I really can't get my head around how to do it.
I am using SSRS 2012, I am relatively new to it and SE, so I apologize if I am lacking any crucial information.

Example of the input data, regarding the favorite things of totally real people:

[image]

The result I would like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do something similar with SSRS.

First you have to map your dataset to a list. Inside the list you insert some text boxes and format them acording to the layout you desire.

[image: basic layout]

Now in the report properties you configure to have three columns.

[image: report Properties]

The tricky part is to adjust the widths and margins so the objects fit nicely in your page. For a letter size page (8.5 x 11 in) the list object should have a width less than 2.83 inches and a height of less than 3.66 inches to give space for the page and column margins.

In the preview check the print layout. You should see something like this:

[image]

The order is not exactly what you asked for, but if this is to print labels I guess it wont matter.

Comment: This worked perfectly, super simple and easily expandable for different purposes. Thanks Adán!

Comment: @Bazul Glad I could help.